# How to authenticate folders and files for a particular user in a Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

In other words,

Friend of mine storing files in a separate folder for each user in the server, and how to access those files only for a particular user.

For Ex:

user1, user2, user3 are the folders, user1 should access only user1 folder not others. I am using ASP.NET & C#

I am kinda noob, so ignore if already answer (and kind enough to post the link.)

If this is not the best way, show which method is best for this type of authentication.

Comment: are users allowed to browse for storing and retrieving files?

Comment: @Absi yes, simply like I am planning for a image gallery like structure for users files in their appropirate folder. So the other users and anon users can't view those images even if they know the exact URL

Answer (score 2):

create a web.config file per folder and authorize users:

so for folder user1:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="user1"/>
            <deny users="*"/>

        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I assume you are using Forms Authentication

Comment: @Roger Can this be created dynamically?